# How can I know which ports RStudio uses to get packages from the CRAN?

Tags: r, port, cran, connectivity

I'm trying to set up Rstudio in my new work enviroment. Right now we have a problem as the security is pretty high and I can't download any package into my rstudio session. It shows that the cran is inaccesible. We thought that probably we need to open a port for me to use with RStudio and I've been searching in the manuals and in the web with no results.

Can someone help me please?

I've tried to read into the manuals and into the RStudio archives. In the web people only talked about linux, but in my work enviroment I work in windows. Nothing worked

Comment: According to the [Rstudio Community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/which-ports-are-used-for-install-packages-function/34667) it just uses the normal http and https ports (80 and 443, respectively). If you want to check, see how to [intercept HTTP/HTTPS traffic of one application](https://superuser.com/questions/1354619/intercept-http-https-traffic-of-one-application-windows-10) - there's a Microsoft tool called TCPView and third party apps e.g. Wireshark, Fiddler.